# Javascript - if (arg.match(/^\/.*/)) {}

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using nodejs for a API testing. In order to test the contents of this `if` statement, I need to find a String that will match this regular expression.

```
if (arg.match(/^\/.*/)) {
    // ...
}
```

Can anyone suggest a matching string?

Comment: It's unclear from this question what your problem is. Please can you add a much more detailed explanation so that others can help you.

Comment: Duncan, I'm using nodejs for a API testing. I'm trying to debug few things, i like to get in to this 'if' statement. I'm not sure what kind of string should be passed to get in this 'if'.

Comment: You're looking for a string that matches this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use http://regexpad.com for testing your regular expressions. It will show you directly the matching texts.

In this case it will be `/a` for example.

Permalink to your example **http://regexpad.com/?r=^\%2F.*&f=&m0=%2Fa#p-javascript**

Comment: When entering the expression on the left, omit the first and last slashes - you can see how it would look in your code on the bottom right.

Answer (score 2):

That pattern will match any string of characters that starts with a forward slash. Try `/foo`.

Comment: i tried this /c/Users/red/Documents/old/. but this doesnt match with that pattern. it skips 'if' :(

Comment: @user1748253 - I suspect your input string wasn't what you thought it was. Are you sure there wasn't any whitespace at the beginning? Here is a screencap of this exact code working in JavaScript: http://i.imgur.com/7W7Iu.jpg

Comment: @user1748253 - And here is the RegexPad version you can run yourself: http://goo.gl/WRIkJ

Comment: got it fixed! you are correct, the shell scripts (which invokes this JS) removes "/" before calling .